# How do I get 'date-1' formatted as mm-dd-yyyy using PowerShell?

Tags: date, powershell, formatting

How does one get *date-1* and format it to mm-dd-yyyy in PowerShell?

Example: If today is November 1, 2013, and I need 10-31-2013 in my code.

I've used AddDays(-1) before, but I can't seem to get it to work with any formatting options.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use the .tostring() method with datetime format specifiers to format to whatever you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
11-01-2013
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If your question has been answered, would you please mark it so?

Answer (score 14):

I think this is only partially true. Changing the format seems to switch the date to a string object which then has no methods like AddDays to manipulate it. So to make this work, you have to switch it back to a date. For example:

```
Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -format D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Windows PowerShell
    Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    PS C:\Windows\system32> **$dte = Get-Date**
    PS C:\Windows\system32> **$PastDueDate = $dte.AddDays(-45).Date**
    PS C:\Windows\system32> **$PastDueDate**

    Sunday, March 1, 2020 12:00:00 AM

   PS C:\Windows\system32> **$NewDateFormat = Get-Date $PastDueDate -Format MMddyyyy**
   PS C:\Windows\system32> **$NewDateFormat 03012020**
```

There're few additional methods available as well e.g.: `$dte.AddDays(-45).Day`

Comment: The `-Format` parameter is just a wrapper for the `ToString()` method. Therefore, your answer does not differ from the already accepted answer, except you subtract 45 days intead of the desired 1 day and do not include the desired dashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple solution for me:

## just the current date

```
$tStamp = Get-Date -format yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss
```

## current date with some months added

```
$tStamp = Get-Date (get-date).AddMonths(6).Date -Format yyyyMMdd
```

Answer (score 0):

Using system reference :

```
 [System.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
```