# Change of format Get-Date` PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How to do `Get-Date` to show me this format 2018-01-10 and that does not show the time?

I was currently using `Get-Format s` but it shows me time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get 'date-1' formatted as mm-dd-yyyy using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741716/how-do-i-get-date-1-formatted-as-mm-dd-yyyy-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other method (without get-date):

```
[System.DateTime]::Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. For instance you could use the `-Format` parameter of the cmdlet:

```
Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

You could use the `ToString()` method of the `DateTime` object the cmdlet produces:

```
(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

You could also use PowerShell's format operator (`-f`):

```
'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell Script to get date as requested

```
get-date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
```

Following doc will give you brief explanation on formats

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx